# Ping between hosts with separate subnet

Tags: linux, networking, router, switch, subnet

I have two hosts with different subnet

Host1(Linux) has Ip Address of 172.29.1.xxx 
Host2 has IP Address of 192.168.1.xxx

Host2 with 192 address can ping the host1 and all the servers with 172 address
Host1 with 172 address can only ping the gateway of 192 i.e 192.168.1.1 but cannot ping any other servers with 192 address including host2.

I tried adding static route on host1 with these but it doesn't change anything

ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0

ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 172.29.1.1 dev eth0

Can you please help me out with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue on the gateways. Since 172.x.x.x servers can respond to 192.x.x.x, routes are correct. Check firewall/gateway rules.